# replace the characters ( '-' to '/' ) in date column in R

Tags: r, str-replace

In date column ,
I need to change ' 04-04-2020' to ' 04/04/2020'
then I need to convert to datetime.

i did it with stringr

after printing it shows all NAN.

Answer (score 2):

**Replace Specific Characters in String in R**

You can try this :

**1. Using gsub() function**

Syntax: gsub(character,new_character, string)

```
print(gsub("-", "/", "04-02-2022") )
```

the output will be like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqeLr.png)

**2. Using str_replace_all() function**

str_replace_all() is also a function that replaces the character with a particular character in a string. It will replace all occurrences of the character. It is available in stringr package. So, we need to install and load the package

```
install: install.packages("stringr")

load: library("stringr")
```

Syntax: str_replace_all(string, “character”, “new_character”)

```
# load the stringr package
library("stringr")

print(str_replace_all("-", "/", "04-02-2022") )
```

#R #specificcharacter #replacestring